# why moving immediate value to register then adding it to second register is faster then add immediate value?

Tags: x86, inline-assembly, micro-optimization, amd-processor

Why is moving immediate value to register then adding it to second register is faster then add immediate value?

```
;this is faster, test result : 1976.805144 cycles
mov     eax,7efefeffh
add     ebx, eax

;this is slower, test result : 2009.428059 cycles
add     ebx,7efefeffh
```

Note:
The results are for Application benchmark test, not the for these instruction only, however
There are no other changes in code what-so-ever
Same Test data used for both
The result varies by +/- 5 Cycles.
I have an AMD E350 processor.

Comment: Probably the larger code resulted in different alignment for later instructions, and that happened to make the difference.  Or else there's a false dependency through EAX or AL in a loop this is part of.  According to Agner Fog's microarch guide (https://agner.org/optimize/), `add ebx, imm32` is a single uop that decodes efficiently on AMD's Bobcat microarch (That's what an E350 is: https://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-E-350-Notebook-Processor.40941.0.html).  We need a real [mcve] that contains a full loop, not just the instructions you changed, to be able to say anything useful.